# Vector differentiation

Tags: calculus

I have a surface, $S$, defined parametrically as following

$S(u,v)= \langle u^2+v^2,u^2,v^2 \rangle$

its partial derivatives are

$S_u(u,v)= \langle 2u,2u,0 \rangle$

$S_v(u,v)= \langle 2v,0,2v \rangle$

Knowing this, I proceed to create a new surface as following

$S'(u,v)=S(u,v) + T(u,v)*n$

where $S'(u,v)$ is the new surface generated by a point on the surface, $S(u,v)$,

$T(u,v)$, is just a scalar function

and $n$ is the unit surface normal at that given point, that is calculated as following

$n=\dfrac {S_u(u,v) \times S_v(u,v)}{||S_u(u,v) \times S_v(u,v)||}$

My problem is how to obtain the partial derivatives from the new surface

$S'_u(u,v)=S_u(u,v) + T_u(u,v)*n + T(u,v)*n_u$
$S'_v(u,v)=S_v(u,v) + T_v(u,v)*n + T(u,v)*n_v$

I don't know how to calculated the corresponding $n_u$ and $n_v$

The textbook says, *$n$ is itself a vector-valued function of $u$ and $v$. The vectors $n_u$ and $n_v$ depend on the curvature of the surface $S$. Normally this curvature is so small that $||n_u||$ and $||n_v||$ are negligible.*

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be correct but lets call $w = S_u(u,v) \times S_v(u,v)$. Then $n = \frac{w}{\vert \vert w \vert \vert}$.

So then calculating out $w$ we get $w = (4 uv, -4 uv, -4uv)$.

Then $n = \left(\frac{u v}{\sqrt{3} \left| u v\right| },-\frac{u v}{\sqrt{3} \left| u v\right|
   },-\frac{u v}{\sqrt{3} \left| u v\right| }\right)$.

Basically $n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \text{sgn}(u v)(1, -1, -1)$

Comment: thanks for you reply, how did you get $w=(4v^2,−4uv,4v^2)$, my cross product calculation gives me the following result $w=<4uv,-4uv,-4uv>$

Comment: Yes you are correct, I had a typo in my mathematica code. I'll adjust the answer momentarily.

Comment: Hi, can you give a glimpse why the text book says that *Normally this curvature is so small that $||nu||$ and $||nv||$ are negligible.* ? Because my calculations of these two vectors never gives me a negligible vector length.